# flask | получить содержимое url в адресной строке

Tags: python, flask

Я хочу получить и записать содержимое URL, идущее после 127.0.0.1:5000/ полностью в переменную.

Например, **127.0.0.1:5000/asf?/.asd/**

В переменную хочу записать **asf?/.asd**

Обычный роут `@app.route('/<path:path>')` не подойдет.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть какие-то может быть костыльные методы это сделать?

Comment: `@app.route('/')` и проверять значение `request.full_path`

Comment: `request.args.get` смотрели?